# Javascript - gameloop using delta time

Tags: javascript, requestanimationframe, game-loop

I am trying to implement a gameloop that uses delta time. I got the following code from [this article](http://codeincomplete.com/posts/2013/12/4/javascript_game_foundations_the_game_loop/), however I feel it does not explain this type of gameloop well. I have researched on requestAnimationFrame and none of the explenations seem to be useful. Can someone simply break down how this loop works?

```
function timestamp() {
   return window.performance && window.performance.now ? window.performance.now() : new Date().getTime();
},

var now,
dt   = 0,
last = timestamp(),
step = 1/60;

function frame() {
  now = timestamp();
  dt = dt + Math.min(1, (now - last) / 1000);
  while(dt > step) {
    dt = dt - step;
    update(step);
  }
  render(dt);
  last = now;
  requestAnimationFrame(frame);
}

requestAnimationFrame(frame);
```

Answer (score 4):

`requestAnimationFrame` is a special timer. Unlike `setInterval` which executes the callback repeatedly after a given minimum of milliseconds, `requestAnimationFrame` executes variably to achieve smooth framerates.

The problem is how `requestAnimationFrame` achieves that. Depending on the situation, it may run faster or slower. What this means is that if your update logic was tied to `requestAnimationFrame` directly, a character running at "one step per update" would travel 60 steps in one second when `requestAnimationFrame` is running at 60fps, but then would only do 40 when it throttles down to 40fps.

To counteract this sudden speed-up/slow-down of the timer, we use "delta time". Instead of depending on each iteration of `requestAnimationFrame` to call an update, you check the time between frames to see if it is the right time to call an update.

So lets say your character should do a step every 100ms. If the game ran at 60fps, 100ms is roughly every 6 frames. This means that for each iteration, your code checks to see if 100ms has elapsed. Around the 6th frame it does, and calls update. Now if the timer ran at 40fps, 100ms is around 4 frames. So same logic, on each iteration it checks if 100ms elapsed. At the 4th frame it does and calls update. With this, you are insured that update is consistently being called regardless of the fluctuations.

Comment: upvote
     
 
...also mentioning that the current version of `requestAnimationFrame` automatically feeds a timestamp to the animation function. You can use that timestamp to calculate how much time has elapsed since you were last in the animation loop. Importantly: That elapsed time can be used to move your character based on elapsed time rather than on (possibly irregular) animation loop count

Comment: Any efficient way to calculate time since last frame?