# using delta time with javascript

Tags: javascript, time, timedelta

i have been seeing a few answers relating to delta time in javascript
eg; [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31998251/javascript-gameloop-using-delta-time) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13996267/loop-forever-and-provide-delta-time/14006703) but i do not understand how they work, or more rather how i would use them.

currently i just have a main loop that follows this structure

```
var main = function ()
{
    doStuff();
    setTimeout(main,1)
}
main()
```

but i have found an issue which causes frame drops and thus i now need to use delta time.

how would i edit my main loop to include delta time?

Comment: MDN docs for [`window.requestAnimationFrame`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame) have a good example. If you don't understand it (or one of the answers you linked), you should say specifically what part is giving you trouble. Specifically, what do you not understand about it?

Comment: Amadan: where would i put my code into? does that example loop? it doesnt appear as such although it is almost definetly a method ive never seen before

Comment: RAF does almost exactly the same thing as `setTimeout`, with two differences: RAF will invoke the callback as soon as it can (so no need, or way, to pass the delay time), and it will provide the callback with the high-resolution timestamp telling it when exactly it was executed. Your `main` is thus almost equivalent to `step` from the example. The RAF call outside the function schedules the first callback; the RAF at the end of the function schedules the next one as the last one is finishing, which constitutes a loop (to break it, conditionally avoid invoking RAF inside the function).

Comment: it works, but it stops after 2 seconds approx for some reason

Comment: It's impossible to tell you anything unless we see a [example] of your code.

Comment: Yes, it will stop working after sometime by the browser as your are using 1 millisecond.. you have to increase time